# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds present, but not expected, when run inside another class

Tags: java

```
Random random = new Random();
int numDigits;
int[] secretNumber = new int[numDigits];

public int[] convertNumToDigitArray(String number){
    int[] numToDigitArray = new int[numDigits];
    for (int i = 0; i<number.length(); i++){
        numToDigitArray[i] = number.charAt(i);
    }
    return numToDigitArray;
}

public int getNumDigits(){
    return numDigits;
    }

public int[] getSecretNumber(){
    return secretNumber;
    }

public void setNumDigits(int numDigits){
    this.numDigits=numDigits;
}

public void generateNewSecret(){
    int number = random.nextInt(((int)Math.pow(10, numDigits) - ((int)Math.pow(10, numDigits-1)))) + ((int)Math.pow(10, numDigits-1));
    int temporary = numDigits;
    for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++){
        secretNumber[i] = (int)(number/(Math.pow(10, temporary--)));   //here's where the exception is thrown!
        if (number < 10)
            break;
        number = number%((int)(Math.pow(10, temporary--)));
        temporary--;  
        }
    }
```

Hi all, I am stuck on a problem and need some help. I have written (and am debugging) a program that generates a number, puts that number in an array, and then compares a user guess to that number. The point I am stuck at is when the computer generates the number, the array I am putting it in is throwing an exception that the index is out of bounds. That must mean that (to my knowledge) the index is below zero. But when I run the program separately and check the index, it starts at 0. The method in question runs independently and generates the array without throwing the exception, but when it's called from the 'mother program' the exception is thrown. It points to the line in the code where the array is being filled inside a loop here.

Any help would be super appreciated :)

Comment: `secretNumber` has 0 elements!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad secret number is set by a scanner in a separate class

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that `numDigits` always equals the number of elements in the `secretNumber` array:

```
public void setNumDigits(int numDigits){
    this.numDigits=numDigits;
    // Add this line
    secretNumber = new int[numDigits];
}
```

Currently you can set `numDigits` to a value that is higher than the array size. This is what can lead to the error in the `for` loop on `secretDigits` limited by the `numDigits`.

Comment: @user2242743 your `convertNumToDigitArray` should also declare the array to be the length of the input string and not the `numDigits`.  Further, `convertNumToDigitArray` has a precondition that `generateNewSecret` be called before it is called since that is where you initialize `numDigits`.  If I were grading this, you would lose points so you may want to refactor a bit once you get things working.